# How to facet the raw data when plotting the predicted values in two facets?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, predict

I like to `facet_grid` a variable of my model and concurrently plot the raw data. Though, the raw data is the same in both facets:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggeffects)
data(mtcars)

mtcars <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(cyl = as.factor(cyl),
         vs = as.factor(vs))

m <- lm(mpg ~ cyl * am, data = mtcars)

pred <- ggpredict(m, , terms = c("cyl", "am"), type = "fe")

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = mtcars,
             aes(x = cyl, y = mpg),
             position = position_dodge2(0.7)) +
  geom_errorbar(data = pred,
                aes(x = x, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high)) +
  facet_grid(~ group)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to `rename()` the column `group` of the `pred` dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggeffects)
data(mtcars)

mtcars <- mtcars %>%
  mutate(cyl = as.factor(cyl),
         vs = as.factor(vs))

m <- lm(mpg ~ cyl * am, data = mtcars)

pred <- ggpredict(m, , terms = c("cyl", "am"), type = "fe") %>%
  rename(am = group) # You have to rename 'group'

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = mtcars,
             aes(x = cyl, y = mpg),
             position = position_dodge2(0.7)) +
  geom_errorbar(data = pred,
                aes(x = x, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high)) +
  facet_grid(~ am)
```

[image]